# How to take specific rows from and add them to a subset

Tags: r

I want to take specific rows from a dataset(f.e. **datasetA**) and add them to a subset or a different dataset, lets say **datasetB**. The row **numbers** and only the **numbers** that i want to take from **datasetA** are stored into a different dataset(datasetROWS), that only contains the row numbers that i want. How can i do that?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.  Instructions can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
newdataset<-rbind(datasetB,datasetA[datasetROWS,])
```

This assumes `datasetROWS` is a vector and that both datasetA and datasetB have the same columns.

Answer (score -1):

```
 library(tidyverse)
 Data_A <- datasetROWS %>%
    left_join(datasetA,by="row_numbers") #this is the variable you are joining by

 Concatenated_table<-rbind(Data_a,datasetB)
```